# Are there any prequels to 5 Centimeters Per Second?

Tags: 5-centimeters-per-second, makoto-shinkai

I plan on watching 5 Centimeters Per Second and I would like to know if there are any prequels I should watch before I start with it.

Comment: May I know why you thought there's prequel to this movie? Reading Wikipedia, it seems there's only 1 movie with 3 segments.

Comment: There is now a [novel](http://myanimelist.net/manga/34841/Byousoku_5_Centimeter) and a [manga](http://myanimelist.net/manga/23419/Byousoku_5_Centimeter) adaption that may (have not read either) contain more information but I'm not aware of any prequels now or even less back when the movie came out. It's supposed to be as episodic as it is.

Comment: The manga is mostly identical content-wise, except that there's a segment added in the last chapter about Kanae.

Comment: I thought there was a prequel because when I read the Wikipedia it had "Act 1, Act 2, and Act 3" and after doing a bit more research I heard about it having an "Episode 1, Episode 2, etc.". Also, thank you for the help everyone! I appreciate the information you guys have given me

Comment: It was because it was initially released in parts, but they are meant to be one movie. Don't let that confuse you and enjoy the anime. And if you think the answer has satisfied your query, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no prequels. There are also no sequels.

Watch the anime (1 hour runtime; sometimes split into three segments, but they're meant to be watched together). Then, if you'd like, read the manga, which is more or less the same content-wise, but offers a slightly different ending, which

> some might find less soul-crushing.